# Mongoid HABTM inverse of nil not persisting children with concat or =

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I have a `Group` model that HABTM `things`:

```
class Group
  has_and_belongs_to_many :things, inverse_of: nil
end
```

In console:

```
group = Group.last
group.valid?
>> true
group.persisted?
>> true

array_of_things = [thing1, thing2]

group.things.concat array_of_things
>> [object1, object2]
group.reload.things
>> []

group.things = array_of_things
>> [object1, object2]
group.reload.things
>> []
```

Moped logger for both cases:

```
UPDATE       database=bd collection=groups selector={:_id=>BSON::ObjectId('123')} update={"$push"=>{"thing_ids"=>[BSON::ObjectId('456'), BSON::ObjectId('789')]}} flags=[:multi]
COMMAND      database=bd command={:getlasterror=>1, :w=>1} runtime: 0.7225ms
```

This works:

```
array_of_things.each { |thing| group.things << thing }
group.reload.things
>> [thing1, thing2]
```

Logger:

```
UPDATE       database=bd collection=groups selector={"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('123')} update={"$addToSet"=>{"thing_ids"=>{"$each"=>[BSON::ObjectId('456')]}}} flags=[]
COMMAND      database=bd command={:getlasterror=>1, :w=>1} runtime: 0.5413ms
UPDATE       database=bd collection=groups selector={"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('123')} update={"$addToSet"=>{"thing_ids"=>{"$each"=>[BSON::ObjectId('789')]}}} flags=[]
COMMAND      database=bd command={:getlasterror=>1, :w=>1} runtime: 0.3517ms
```

I don't know if `:getlasterror=>1` has something to do but in the second case is persisted.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

PS: Mongoid 4  (master branch), Ruby 2 and Rails 4.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't see the problem you're seeing.  That is, I get:

```
group.things.concat array_of_things
>> [object1, object2]
group.reload.things
>> [object1, object2]

group.things = array_of_things
>> [object1, object2]
group.reload.things
>> [object1, object2]
```

I'm running an older version of mongoid (2.4.12).

I noticed you had a typo, when you do `reload`, you did it on `groups` but it should be on `group`. Could this be the reason you're not getting what you're expecting?

Comment: It used to work in older versions of mongoid. Thanks for the typo.